# How to decompress jpeg bytes in Dot Net Core?

Tags: c#, image-processing, jpeg, .net-core

I'm looking at porting some code to dot net core so I can run it on Linux. One part of the code needs to decompress a jpeg file and read the pixel values.

It seems that neither System.Drawing.Bitmap nor System.Windows.Media is available in Dot Net Core.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: These classes use native GDI functionality on Windows

Comment: Yep. So whats the Dot Net Core alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 3rd party library for this purpose; take a look to the [ImageProcessorCore](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/tree/Core) (it can be installed from myget: https://www.myget.org/gallery/imageprocessor ):

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("foo.jpg")) {
  Image image = new Image(stream);
  using (PixelAccessor<Color, uint> pixels = image.Lock()) {
    var pixelColor = pixels[0,0];
  }
}
```